# auto backup of Oracle materialized view

Tags: oracle

Is there anyway in Oracle 12c to automatically make a copy of a materialized view and keep it before you refresh the view.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: How do you refresh the mview?

Comment: We refresh with the Oracle scheduler but I would be open to other ideas.  We are just in the building process.

Answer (score 0):

Write a procedure where you

1. backup the mview
2. refresh the mview

Execute this procedure by scheduler job